# how to copy x days old files from folders and subfolders to new location while maintaining current folder structure in windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have 3 Application servers and 3 Web servers. Each of them generates logs on their own machine.
The log file path is shared on a separate machine (all are Windows Machines).

Logs location for App servers:

```
 Source_App1=\\192.168.1.x\d$\Temp\ErrorLog 
 Source_App2=\\192.168.2.x\d$\Temp\ErrorLog 
 Source_App3=\\192.168.3.x\d$\Temp\ErrorLog
```

Under above each location there are 4 folders, say `folder1`, `folder2`, `folder3`, `folder4`. this is where all log files of Application server is created.

Logs location for Web servers:

```
Source_Web1=\\192.168.4.x\d$\Temp\ErrorLog
Source_Web2=\\192.168.5.x\d$\Temp\ErrorLog
Source_Web3=\\192.168.6.x\d$\Temp\ErrorLog
```

Under above each location there are 4 folders, say `folder1`, `folder2`, `folder3`, `folder4`. This is where all log files of Web server is created.

I want to move `X` days old logs files from each of the location to a single separate location:

```
Destination=\\192.168.7.x\D$\backups\Prod App & Web Error Logs Backup\
```

Under above destination location it should create two folders like `App` and `Web`.

Now I want to copy all `App1`, `App2`, `App3` folders to destination `App` folder.

And `Web1`, `Web2`, `Web3` to destination `Web` folder.

But the directory structure should be created automatically.

I tried:

```
for /D %i in ("%Source_App1%*") do if not exist "%Destination%\App\App1\%i" mkdir "%Destination%\App\App1\%i"
```

But it is not working.

Can you please help me in this?

Answer (score 2):

This sound like a perfect job for the [`forfiles` command](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) which is capable of filtering for files and directories of a certain age (by last modification date, the time is not regarded):

```cmd
@echo off

rem // Define constants:
set "Source_App1=\\192.168.1.x\d$\Temp\ErrorLog"
set "Source_App2=\\192.168.2.x\d$\Temp\ErrorLog"
set "Source_App3=\\192.168.3.x\d$\Temp\ErrorLog"
set "Source_Web1=\\192.168.4.x\d$\Temp\ErrorLog"
set "Source_Web2=\\192.168.5.x\d$\Temp\ErrorLog"
set "Source_Web3=\\192.168.6.x\d$\Temp\ErrorLog"
set "Destination=\\192.168.7.x\D$\backups\Prod App & Web Error Logs Backup"
set "Destination_App=%Destination%\App"
set "Destination_Web=%Destination%\Web"
set "X=7" & rem // (minimum age of files in days to copy)

rem // Process App servers:
set /A "IDX=0"
for /D %%D in (
    "%Source_App1%\*"
    "%Source_App2%\*"
    "%Source_App3%\*"
) do (
    for /F %%C in ('set /A "IDX+=1"') do (
        set /A "IDX=%%C"
        pushd "%%~D"
        forfiles /D -%X% /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE (2> nul mkdir 0x22%Destination_App%\App%%C\%%~nxD0x22 & copy @path 0x22%Destination_App%\App%%C\%%~nxD0x22)"
        popd
    )
)

rem // Process Web servers:
set /A "IDX=0"
for /D %%D in (
    "%Source_Web1%\*"
    "%Source_Web2%\*"
    "%Source_Web3%\*"
) do (
    for /F %%C in ('set /A "IDX+=1"') do (
        set /A "IDX=%%C"
        pushd "%%~D"
        forfiles /D -%X% /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE (2> nul mkdir 0x22%Destination_Web%\Web%%C\%%~nxD0x22 & copy @path 0x22%Destination_Web%\Web%%C\%%~nxD0x22)"
        popd
    )
)
```

---

Here is a more flexible approach that allows a variating amount of server paths. The name of the sub-directory on the destination server is derived from the portion of the source variable names between `Source_` and the numeric digit (`App` and `Web` in the given example); another sub-directory therein is created with the same name, but with the trailing numeric portion included (`App1`, etc., and `Web1`, etc.):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants:
set "Source_App1=\\192.168.1.x\d$\Temp\ErrorLog"
set "Source_App2=\\192.168.2.x\d$\Temp\ErrorLog"
set "Source_App3=\\192.168.3.x\d$\Temp\ErrorLog"
set "Source_Web1=\\192.168.4.x\d$\Temp\ErrorLog"
set "Source_Web2=\\192.168.5.x\d$\Temp\ErrorLog"
set "Source_Web3=\\192.168.6.x\d$\Temp\ErrorLog"
set "Destination=\\192.168.7.x\D$\backups\Prod App & Web Error Logs Backup"
set "X=7" & rem // (minimum age of files in days to copy)

rem // Process App and Web servers:
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A in ('2^> nul set Source_') do (
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=_" %%C in ("%%A") do (
        for /F "tokens=1 delims=0123456789" %%D in ("%%C") do (
            for /D %%E in ("%%B\*") do (
                pushd "%%~E"
                forfiles /D -%X% /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE (2> nul mkdir 0x22%Destination%\%%D\%%C\%%~nxE0x22 & copy @path 0x22%Destination%\%%D\%%C\%%~nxE0x22)"
                popd
            )
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply. i will try it and update here in few minutes.

Comment: i apologies for late reply, i was busy in other work, I have tried this solution, but i am getting UNC error as " ERROR: UNC paths (\\machine\share) are not supported.". How to solve this without using "net use"?

Comment: There were some typos in the code -- please see my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42782079/4)...

Comment: Thanks, aschipfl !!,
Now both the solutions working fine, but this is combining all servers log in single folder under "App" and Web, its not creating separate folders as App1,App2,App3 and Web1,Web2,And Web3 Under parent folder "App" and "Web" on destination.

Can you please do something for this too, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Your question does not clearly mention the sub-directories, or I did not understand it correctly; anyway, their creation has been implemented now...